# SQL query for http requests

Tags: sql

I have a problem with a SQL query.

I must write a query that it will be used from a http request. It will have 3 parameters for users to fill. It will not mandatory to fill all them.

They will fill anything they want. So my problem is how my query can understand that.

The database is simple.

```
create table trdr(
    trdr int,
    name varchar(255),
    email varchar(255),
    address varchar(255),
    zip int,
    district varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    phone01 int,
    phone02 int
    );

insert into trdr(trdr,name,email,address,zip,district,city,phone01,phone02)
values (1,'1','1@1.gr','1',11111,'1','1',231011111,1111111111),(2,'2','2@2.gr','2',22222,'2','2',231011111,222222222);
```

I have written this SQL:

```
select 
    trdr, name, email, isactive, address, zip, district, city, country, phone01, phone02
from 
    trdr
where 
    sodtype = 13 
    and company = 1001 
    and (phone01 = '{param1}' or phone02 = '{param2}' or email = '{param3}')
```

The problem is that when I fill phone01 and phone02 it will show me 2 registrations. I want to show me only the one. I can do that with the "AND"
but it will be wrong when i fill only one variable.
Can i make something to read if my variable(param1,param2,param3) is null?

Anyone can help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: I removed the conflicting tags; please tag the *actual* RDBMS you are using.

Comment: My bad. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Providing ddl (create table) and sample data (insert statements) would  make this a lot easier to understand and help.

Comment: I try to explain it with more details. If you have any suggestions please ad a comment